# Access user folders via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, security, permission

When I am using Terminal to go to different folders such as Documents, Downloads, Photos etc I get presented with a dialog requesting me to grant Terminal access to these folders such as below:

[image]

Is there anyway to bypass this by using Sudo rights in Terminal such as:

```
$ sudo cd ~/Downloads
```

Unfortunately doing the above still shows the dialog when I was expecting the password to be enough. Is there any way to grant permission via terminal?

My OS is Catalina

Comment: Have you tried adding terminal.app to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access?

Comment: Can it be added via Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Open up security preferences.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210595

Add Terminal app to full disk access, same as described for the `systemsetup` command.